# Calculating Billing Weeks based on billing week date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given the following dates:
Start Date: 09/17/2015
End Date 04/01/2016

I am attempting to calculate the total number of weeks and the billing weeks per month, billing weeks to date, and forecasted billing weeks.

Since our billing is only done by week to avoid prorating, this is a little difficult.

I.e,

The total number of weeks would be 29 using the following:

```
(select ceiling(convert(float,DATEDIFF(day,'09/17/2015','04/01/2016')+1)/7))
```

More over if I were to run this report on 8th of Jan 2016,

It should give me 1 week as the billing weeks billed to date, with the remaining 4 weeks as a forecast.

I was thinking of creating a couple of fields:
WeekStart and WeekEnd as dates fields, Month and Year field. And then to filter by dates where end date < today's date. Then aggregate that by the current month.

Example:

Weekstart: 09/17/2015 
Weekend: 09/23/2015
Month: September
Year: 2015

Weekstart: 09/24/2015
Weekend: 09/30/2015
Month: September 
Year: 2015

......
......
......

Weekstart: 03/31/2016
Weekend: 04/06/2016
Year: 2016
Month: March

Does this sound logical?

How can I go about creating this stored procedure. Any  starting point would be very helpful.

Here is the quick sample Stored Proc I have created:

Here is the following sample I created, this should would I believe:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '09/17/2015'
DECLARE @enddate datetime = '04/01/2016'

WHILE (@startdate <= @enddate)
BEGIN
    Print CONVERT(VARCHAR, @startdate, 120) + '-----'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateAdd(DD,+6,@startdate), 120) 
    set @startdate = DateAdd(DD,+6,@startdate)+1 ; 
END
```

Comment: not sure what you call 'a week'. Is this Mon-Sun, Sun-Sat, or just clumps of 7 days? and how you treat partial week? and weeks between months? Why not use the week number for the year with SELECT DATEPART( wk, @Dt) ?

Comment: That shouldn't matter a week will always consist from the day of the week. 
And there are no partial week would be rounded up.

Week is the smallest unit of our measurement

Comment: But that bring me to the next question. If i were to run this report, the current date being: 2016/02/08., how would I get it so that it only picks up data until the week (2016/01/28 - 2016/02/03). Because the 6th falls into the next billing week which has not completed as of yet.

Comment: It clearly does matter how you define  'a week' and/or 'a billing week' because if for no other reason you have to communicate to us and to your users. Note it is you who used both terms so there must be a difference between them in your mind. So, please, don't put off the inevitable: Define 'a week' and define 'a billing week' and then code to those definitions.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Billing Week is defined as 7 inclusive days from the start of the usage period. I.e as shown in the example above.

Comment: i am still unclear on what is  a week in your mind. I think you mean 'blocks of seven days, starting arbitrarily on the first day of service' or something like that. in that case just use math: CEILING(days / 7)

Comment: @RicardoC Yes that is exactly correct.